# Can't show a nagivationbar after hiding it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following in the mainwindow.xib

1. Navigation Controller

   - List item
2. Tab bar controller

   - tabbar
   - firstViewController
   - SecondViewController

The entrypoint

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tabBarController];
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and now in the first viewcontroller i'm writing

```
-(void)loadView
{
    if(rootAppDelegate==nil)
        rootAppDelegate=(tabbarAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    listEmergencyItems= rootAppDelegate.listOfEmergencySectionItems;
    self.rootAppDelegate.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [super loadView];
}
```

and in the second viewcontroller i'm writing

```
- (void)loadView
{    
    if(rootAppDelegate==nil){
        rootAppDelegate=(tabbarAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    }
    listHospitalsItems= self.rootAppDelegate.listOfHospitalsItems;
    self.rootAppDelegate.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [super loadView];
}
```

And on the runtime, when it first loads the first view, i see the navigationbar where i need to navigate into a detail view.
And when i press the second tab bar item, i go to the second view, and the navigation bar gets hidden.
But when i press back on the first tabbar item, i.e. returning to the first viewcontroller. the navigation bar remains hidden.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation bar won't show in the second view because neither view was placed on the navigationcontroller's stack. you want to use something like this in the parent to present a child view instead of overriding loadView

```
    ViewToPresentViewController *myVController = [[ViewToPresentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewToPresentViewController"
                                                                                                                bundle:nil];
            myVController.property = someValue;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myVController
                                                 animated:YES];
    [myVController release];
```

then, as i said previously, you can just use [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:]

Comment: my problem was that whenever i hide it, i couldn't bring it to be viewed again. But you were right about the view not being placed on the navigationcontroller's stack. Thus i made a design mistake. I don't think this can be fixed unless i redesign my application (views and the navigation controller). Thanks anyway.